# Create a very basic countdown in jquery

Tags: jquery

I see these countdown plugins and countdown snippits for 5 seconds. But I am looking to use jquery, with out additional plugins to crate a 30 minute timer that changes the text inside of a h2 tag to count down:

```
<h2>30m</h2> .... <h2>29m</h2> //and so on.
```

How would this be achieved? After the countdown it should do something.

Comment: See this: [JavaScript Timing Events](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **h2** should contain the initial minutes value, like "30". The code will look like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  setInterval(function() {
    min = parseInt($('h2').text()) - 1;
    $('h2').html(min);
    if (min == 0) {
      // Do Something
    }
  }, 60000);
});
```

Comment: interval 60000 will call this function every 60mins ;) you probably want to change it to 5000

Comment: @LorDex - no, 60,000 milliseconds is 1 minute.

Comment: ah, yes, my bad, anyway he wants to run it every 5s

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice that he wants to run it every 5 seconds, this runs every 1 minute. Will update the answer!

Comment: Again, no haha. He wants minutes-timer he was just mentioning the 5-second timers at first!